Problemas para dar ancho a columna de table usando boostrap y datable?
hace unos días creé una tabla y le di estilos usando las librerías de Boostrap 3.3.6 y la Databletable 1.11.5:
<table id="texample" class="table dataTable no-footer" style="border: none; width: 100% !important" aria-describedby="texample">
    <thead style="border: none !important;">
        <tr class="system">
            <th class="text-center sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=""></th>
            <th class="text-center sorting sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="texample" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Examen: Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente">Examen</th>
            <th style="width: 300px !important;" class="text-center sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="01-03-2024(01:34)">01-03-2024(01:34)</th>
            <th style="width: 127px !important" class="text-center sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="02-03-2024(12:49)">02-03-2024(12:49)</th>
            <th style="width: 127px !important" class="text-center sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="10-03-2024(04:54)">10-03-2024(04:54)</th>
            <th style="width: 127px !important" class="text-center sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="10-03-2024(06:04)">10-03-2024(06:04)</th>
            <th style="width: 127px !important" class="text-center sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="11-03-2024(22:14)">11-03-2024(22:14)</th>
            <th style="width: 127px !important" class="text-center sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="12-03-2024(05:12)">12-03-2024(05:12)</th>
            <th style="width: 127px !important" class="text-center sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="12-03-2024(05:28)">12-03-2024(05:28)</th>
            <th style="width: 127px !important" class="text-center sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="12-03-2024(14:38)">12-03-2024(14:38)</th>
            <th style="width: 127px !important" class="text-center sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="12-03-2024(14:41)">12-03-2024(14:41)</th>
            <th style="width: 127px !important" class="text-center sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="13-03-2024(17:01)">13-03-2024(17:01)</th>
            <th style="width: 127px !important" class="text-center sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="13-03-2024(17:42)">13-03-2024(17:42)</th>
            <th style="width: 127px !important" class="text-center sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="14-03-2024(17:10)">14-03-2024(17:10)</th>
            <th style="width: 127px !important" class="text-center sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="18-03-2024(09:40)">18-03-2024(09:40)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="border: none !important;">
        <tr class="odd">
        <td class=" text-center">
            <a class="btn btn-xs btn-info optgraficolis" data-optgraficolis="" data-ex="" rel="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Generar Gráfico"><i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i></a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center sorting_1">UFU</td>  
        <td class=" text-center">-</td>  
        <td class=" text-center">-</td>
        <td style="width: 127px !important" class=" text-center">18,1</td>  
        <td class=" text-center">-</td>  <td class=" text-center">-</td>  
        <td class=" text-center">-</td>  <td class=" text-center">-</td>  
        <td class=" text-center">-</td>  <td class=" text-center">-</td>
        <td style="width: 127px !important" class=" text-center">12,4</td>  
        <td class=" text-center">-</td>  <td class=" text-center">-</td>  
        <td class=" text-center">-</td></tr>
        </tbody>
</table>

Aunque cumple su función esta no me permite cambiar el width de las columnas, lo he intentado de todo:

Agregarles width, tanto a los th como a los td
Usar por Jquery el columnDefs con target de Datatable.
Deshabilitar el autoWidth en la inicialización del Datable
Almacenar la table en un div contenedor y a este quitarle el padding

Lo que note es que el contenido del td cambia el ancho de toda la columna.
Como puedo realmente darle el width a las columnas?

Creo que estás mezclando demasiadas cosas a la vez y estás complicando el renderizado de la página. Por partes: ¿porque usas bootstrap 3 si es del año 2013? ¿porque usas estilos personalizados (atributo style) si usas bootstrap y datatables? Bootstrap está pensado para uniformizar la visualización en todo tipo de dispositivos y cualquier estilo que lo sobreescriba va a darte problemas. Cuando dices de cambiar el witdh de la columna... te refieres dinámicamente moviendo sus bordes tipo hoja de cálculo?  Eso quizás lo haga datatables, por lo tanto busca por ahí, pero dudo que bootstrap lo haga.

Hola, como dije antes probe de distintas formas, primero usando solo datatable y  luego estilos personalizados sin especificar width en datatable. Cuando digo cambiar el width de la columna me refiero a que por ejemplo, siempre tenga una ancho de 127px.

Pues tal como lo estabas haciendo (usando el style y el !important) ya deberia ser suficiente, y si ves que alguna columna se hace más grande ponle un atributo de estilo overflow con el valor hidden o scroll o auto para que no lo haga. (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/overflow). O clases overflow de bootstrap como text-overflow en bootstrap 3.3

Veo que eso del overflow no funciona a la primera. Hay que meterle un table-layout: fixed; a los estilos de la tabla. Aqui mas info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509711/why-does-overflowhidden-not-work-in-a-td

@masterguru, te sucedió que al usar table-layout: fixed las 2 primeras columnas fueron sobrepuestas por las columnas fechas?

Bueno, yo de ti empezaria de 0 usando esa propiedad y vas adecuando las columnas conforme a ello. Piensa que tambien tienes tamaños fijos en los td además de los th, y quizás haya demasiado lio ahora mismo, por eso mejor vuelve a empezar y poco a poco ves corrigiendo lo que salga mal. Usa jsfiddle para jugar dinámicamente con ello: https://jsfiddle.net/tc8p79d6/

Al final encontré la forma.
Dándole un ancho máximo y ancho mínimo a la columna completa (th y td):
style = "max-width:127px;min-width=127px"

